# Какая функция является синонимичной функции Counter? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.6

Мне нужно создать счётчик элементов, который будет считать, сколько "+1" было создано в текстовом документе, который создается, если его нет, или открывается при его наличии. 
Первая часть кода у меня есть, то есть документ создан, "+1" записывается. Но что делать с счётчиком, ума не приложу. Просмотрела большое количество сайтов, видела разные варианты(count, Сounter, counter().most_common и другие). И наиболее частый вариант это все же функция Counter и count. 
Проблема заключается в том, что у меня похоже отсутствует модуль, который отвечает за эту функцию, а со скачиванием возникают проблемы. Поэтому вопрос: Какой другой функцией можно заменить функцию Counter?

Comment: «у меня похоже отсутствует модуль, который отвечает за эту функцию» — как вы это определили?

Comment: @andreymal по наставлению одного человека просмотрела среди модулей, которые существуют. К тому же, при рабочем режиме программы выбивает ошибку, мол эта функция не найдена.

Comment: т.е. в тексте есть символы `+1` и нужно просто посчитать их количество?

Comment: @ViviBush неужели даже `from collections import Counter` не работает?

Comment: @ViviBush покажите пожалуйста ваш код, который не работает

Comment: @gil9red да, и вывести число при помощи print в рабочую область.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk  я не говорила, что код не работает. я сказала, что я без понятия как прописать и, главное, какую функцию для создания счётчика.

Comment: @andreymal прошу прощения. сейчас испробую

Comment: @ViviBush это не то что вы ищите? https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-collections.html

Comment: @andreymal спасибо большое. это как раз таки хоть как-то повлияло на работу программы. немного изменю код и будет просто замечательно. Спасибо. могу я обратиться к вам в дальнейшем при появлении новых вопросов?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk оно самое

Comment: @ViviBush, просто задавайте вопрос - кто-нибудь ответит. Тут не принято задавать вопросы кому-то конкретному.